# How to parse text from PRE tag (seperated by BR)

Tags: excel, parsing, beautifulsoup

```
<pre><pre>Coupon: 0.990<BR>
Date: 07-26-2000     Interest gain: 07-26-2000<BR>
1st Coupon: 08-15-2000 Next Couppn: 02-15-2018<BR>
Frequency: Monthly       Int Calc: ACT/ACT<BR>
1st Var: 08-03-2000 Nxt Var: 02-15-2018<BR>
Var Frq: Weekly<BR>
Init Rt: 4.100</pre></pre>
```

I am trying to parse the contents into tabular format

```
Coupon - 0.990
Date - 07-26-2000
interest gain - 07-26-2000
1st coupon - 08-15-2000
next coupon - 02-15-2018
frequency - Monthly
```

I need to write the output into Excel

Please help.

Comment: <pre><pre>
                        Coupon: 0.990<BR>Date: 07-26-2000     Interest gain: 07-26-2000<BR>1st Coupon: 08-15-2000 Next Coupon: 02-15-2018<BR>Freq: Monthly       Int Calc: ACT/ACT<BR>1st Var: 08-03-2000 Nxt Var: 02-15-2018<BR>Var Frq: Weekly<BR>Init Rt: 4.100</pre>
</pre>

Comment: I cleaned up your question, please check that it's what you intended to ask.

Comment: Thanks Mike, yes I wanted to parse the contents from the HTML into excel sheet in the above listed format.

Comment: trying this and able to get the data into comma separated values but with lot of additional things which I would have to clear conString = " "
strings = str(preTags[4]).split('<br/>')
for s in strings :
    strings2 = s.split(':')
    for t in strings2 :
        conString = conString + ','
        conString = conString + t

print (conString)

Comment: @Praveen Please clarify your question by editing your question; putting the information into a comment is difficult to read and interpret.

Comment: Not familiar with `beautifulsoup` but this can be done relatively easily in VBA, so long as your pattern is similar to what you show.

Comment: Sure Ron Rosenfeld, I would going forward.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to parse this string with a variant of the old cleanup the string and split trick. Your string is divided into rows with `<BR>` and into columns by `:` so:

```
myString = myString.replace("<pre>","");
myString = myString.replace("</pre>","");
myStringArray = myString.split("<BR>");
... loop over myStringArray to process values ...
   myElements = myElement.split(":");
   ... put correct pieces into the table ...
```

I know my answer ignores beautifulsoup, but basic Python seems like enough. My example is pretty much Java/JavaScript pseudo code but you can get the idea from it.

Comment: Sure Michael Shopsin, I was trying that way and would continue to. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
if s.find('1st Coupon:')!= -1:
            firstCoupon = s[s.find("1st"):s.find("N")].split(':')[1]
            nextCoupon = s[s.find("Nxt"): ].split(':')[1]
```

Used the above constructs to split and parse. Issue solved. Thanks all